# Unable to switch between two boto.cfg files

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I have two *boto.cfg* files, one for QA and the other for Production. I can choose dynamically which *boto.cfg* to choose. When I choose QA and call `get_all_buckets()` I get all the buckets of QA. But when I change to Production, it still returns QA buckets. My script is in python.

Is there a way I can disable the boto connection? I have tried to exit from Python and create a new object but it still returns QA buckets although the *boto.cfg* has been updated to Production credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are picking up different credentials?  There is no state retained across different Python sessions.  Try running this little script with each config file:

```
>>> import boto
>>> print boto.config.get_value('Credentials', 'aws_access_key_id')
```

Do you get a different value printed each time?  If not, you could try having two config files, boto1.cfg and boto2.cfg and then setting the environment variable BOTO_CONFIG to point to one or the other.

Comment: Yes when I pass the credentials it works fine! But when I read it from boto.cfg files it does not give correct answers.